React Form Issue passing wrong value
So i have form that I am using to create a project. I can have cover image/video and i can also add extra videos/images to the project. I made a mediaselector that can also upload new videos that are not in the db yet. because I am using mux as a video streamer, i need to check the table when the videos are ready for streaming. this i do with supabase real time. The problem i have is that my mediaselector takes the value of my second mediaselector when i iniate an upload. Due to rerenders the last rendered value wins.so my supabase function gets the wrong value and can never refresh the page so the video is not displayed.
how can i control this ?
 'use client';
    
    // react
    import { useState } from 'react';
    
    // next
    import Image from 'next/image';
    
    import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
    import { format } from 'date-fns';
    // form
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as z from 'zod';

import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { Checkbox } from '@/components/ui/checkbox';
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from '@/components/ui/form';
// components
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { Label } from '@/components/ui/label';
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from '@/components/ui/select';
import { Textarea } from '@/components/ui/textarea';
import { Image as Images, Video } from '@/db/schema';
// utils
import { isRecordOfString } from '@/lib/utils';

import DetailsInput from './details-input';
import { MediaSelector } from './media-selector';
// custom components
import { TagInput } from './tag-input';

type ProjectFormValues = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

interface ProjectFormProps {
  projectData: any | null;
  images: Images[];
  videos: Video[];
}

const formSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(1),
  description: z.string().optional(),
  year: z.number().int().min(1900).max(new Date().getFullYear()).nullable(),
  tags: z.array(z.string()).optional(),
  status: z.enum(['draft', 'published', 'archived']).default('draft'),
  featured: z.boolean().default(false),
  details: z.record(z.string(), z.string()).nullable(),
  media: z
    .array(z.object({ type: z.enum(['url', 'playbackId']), value: z.string() }))
    .max(8)
    .nullable(),
  coverImageUrl: z.string().nullable(),
  coverVideoPlaybackId: z.string().nullable(),
});

export default function ProjectForm({
  projectData,
  images,
  videos,
}: ProjectFormProps) {
  // state
  const [selectedCoverMedia, setSelectedCoverMedia] = useState<{
    type: 'url' | 'playbackId';
    value: string | null;
    identifier?: string;
  } | null>(
    projectData?.coverImageUrl
      ? { type: 'url', value: projectData.coverImageUrl }
      : projectData?.coverVideoPlaybackId
        ? { type: 'playbackId', value: projectData.coverVideoPlaybackId }
        : null,
  );

  const [generalMediaValue, setGeneralMediaValue] = useState<
    { type: 'url' | 'playbackId'; value: string | null; identifier?: string }[]
  >(projectData?.media || []);

  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [tags, setTags] = useState<string[]>(projectData?.tags || []);
  const [details, setDetails] = useState<{ [key: string]: string }>(
    isRecordOfString(projectData?.details) ? projectData.details : {},
  );
  const [isProcessingCover, setIsProcessingCover] = useState(false);

  const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  const yearOptions = Array.from({ length: 6 }, (_, i) => currentYear - i);
  const formattedUpdatedAt = projectData?.updatedAt
    ? format(new Date(projectData.updatedAt), 'MM/dd/yyyy') // Using `MM/dd/yyyy` format
    : 'N/A';

  const form = useForm<ProjectFormValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      title: projectData?.content.title || '',
      description: projectData?.description || '',
      year: projectData?.year || currentYear,
      tags: projectData?.tags || [],
      status: projectData?.status || 'draft',
      featured: projectData?.featured ?? false,
      details: isRecordOfString(projectData?.details)
        ? projectData.details
        : null,
      media: projectData
        ? [
            ...(projectData.images || []).map((image: any) => ({
              type: 'url' as const,
              value: image.url,
            })),
            ...(projectData.videos || []).map((video: any) => ({
              type: 'playbackId' as const,
              value: video.playbackId,
            })),
          ]
        : null,
      coverImageUrl:
        selectedCoverMedia?.type === 'url' ? selectedCoverMedia.value : null,
      coverVideoPlaybackId:
        selectedCoverMedia?.type === 'playbackId'
          ? selectedCoverMedia.value
          : null,
    },
  });

  const { setValue } = form;

  const onSubmit = async (
    values: ProjectFormValues,
    status: 'draft' | 'published',
  ) => {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    try {
      const images = values.media
        ? values.media
            .filter((item) => item.type === 'url')
            .map((item) => item.value)
        : null;
      const videos = values.media
        ? values.media
            .filter((item) => item.type === 'playbackId')
            .map((item) => item.value)
        : null;

      const payload = {
        ...values,
        status,
        images,
        videos,
      };

      console.log('Submitting project:', payload);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* Cover Image Section */}
      <div className="relative mb-4 mt-4 flex h-64 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-md">
        {selectedCoverMedia ? (
          selectedCoverMedia.type === 'url' ? (
            <Image
              src={selectedCoverMedia.value || ''}
              fill
              alt="Selected Media"
              className="rounded-md object-cover"
            />
          ) : isProcessingCover ? (
            <span className="text-muted-foreground">
              Processing video cover... This may take a few minutes.
            </span>
          ) : (
            <Image
              src={`https://image.mux.com/${selectedCoverMedia.value}/thumbnail.webp`}
              fill
              alt="Selected Media GIF"
              className="rounded-md object-cover"
            />
          )
        ) : (
          <span className="text-muted-foreground">
            Please add a cover by selecting a media item.
          </span>
        )}

        <div className="absolute right-2 top-2 flex gap-2">
          <MediaSelector
            images={images}
            videos={videos}
            value={[{ type: 'url', value: 'yes' }]}
            onChange={(mediaItems) => {
              const mediaItem = mediaItems[0];
              console.log('Selected Cover Media:', mediaItem);
              if (mediaItem) {
                console.log('Setting Cover Media:', mediaItem);
                setSelectedCoverMedia(mediaItem);
                if (mediaItem.type === 'url') {
                  form.setValue('coverImageUrl', mediaItem.value);
                  form.setValue('coverVideoPlaybackId', null);
                  setIsProcessingCover(false);
                } else if (mediaItem.type === 'playbackId') {
                  form.setValue('coverVideoPlaybackId', mediaItem.value);
                  form.setValue('coverImageUrl', null);
                  setIsProcessingCover(!mediaItem.value);
                }
              } else {
                setSelectedCoverMedia(null);
                form.setValue('coverImageUrl', null);
                form.setValue('coverVideoPlaybackId', null);
              }
            }}
            maxSelection={1}
            title={selectedCoverMedia ? 'Change Cover' : 'Add Cover'}
            side="left"
          />
          {selectedCoverMedia && (
            <Button
              size="sm"
              variant="outline"
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedCoverMedia(null);
                form.setValue('coverImageUrl', null);
                form.setValue('coverVideoPlaybackId', null);
              }}
            >
              Remove
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <Form {...form}>
          <form className="flex w-full flex-col gap-6">
            <div className="flex justify-between gap-2">
              {/* Name Field */}
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="title"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem className="w-1/2">
                    <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input
                        placeholder={'Enter project title'}
                        {...field}
                        value={field.value || ''}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormDescription>
                      Enter the name of the project
                    </FormDescription>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />

              {/* Year Field */}
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="year"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem className="w-1/2">
                    <FormLabel>Year</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Select
                        onValueChange={(value) =>
                          field.onChange(parseInt(value))
                        }
                        defaultValue={
                          field.value?.toString() || currentYear.toString()
                        }
                      >
                        <SelectTrigger>
                          <SelectValue placeholder="Select Year" />
                        </SelectTrigger>
                        <SelectContent>
                          {yearOptions.map((year) => (
                            <SelectItem key={year} value={year.toString()}>
                              {year}
                            </SelectItem>
                          ))}
                        </SelectContent>
                      </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormDescription>
                      Choose the year when the project was completed.
                    </FormDescription>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
            </div>

            {/* Description Field */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="description"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Description</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Textarea
                      {...field}
                      placeholder="Enter project description"
                      className="w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 p-2"
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>
                    Provide a brief description of the project.
                  </FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            {/* Tags Field */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="tags"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Tags</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <TagInput
                      {...field}
                      placeholder="e.g., design, marketing, video, software"
                      tags={tags}
                      className="sm:min-w-[450px]"
                      setTags={(newTags) => {
                        setTags(newTags);
                        setValue('tags', newTags as [string, ...string[]]);
                      }}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>
                    Add keywords that describe your project. This will help
                    others find it. Example tags could include: industry, type
                    of work, or technology used.
                  </FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            {/* Featured Field */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="featured"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="flex flex-col">
                  <FormLabel>Featured</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-start gap-2">
                      <Checkbox
                        checked={field.value ?? false}
                        onCheckedChange={field.onChange}
                      />
                      <Label className="text-foreground">
                        Mark as Featured
                      </Label>
                    </div>
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>
                    Mark this project as a featured item. Featured projects are
                    highlighted for better visibility.
                  </FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            {/* Details Field */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="details"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Details</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <DetailsInput
                      details={details}
                      setDetails={(newDetails) => {
                        setDetails(newDetails);
                        field.onChange(newDetails);
                      }}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>
                    Add any extra information in key-value pairs. Examples:
                    Technology - React.js, Medium - Video.
                  </FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            {/* Media Items Field */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="media"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Media Items</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <MediaSelector
                      title="Select Media"
                      side="bottom"
                      images={images}
                      videos={videos}
                      value={generalMediaValue}
                      maxSelection={8}
                      onChange={(mediaItems) => {
                        setGeneralMediaValue(mediaItems);
                        field.onChange(mediaItems);
                      }}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>
                    Select up to 8 images or videos that showcase your project.
                    Examples could include screenshots, project photos, or demo
                    videos.
                  </FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            {/* Submit Buttons */}
            <div className="mt-8 flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
              {projectData && (
                <p className="text-muted-foreground text-xs">
                  Last Updated: {formattedUpdatedAt}
                </p>
              )}
              <div className="flex gap-x-2">
                <Button
                  type="button"
                  variant="secondary"
                  onClick={form.handleSubmit((values) =>
                    onSubmit(values, 'draft'),
                  )}
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                >
                  {isSubmitting ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'}
                </Button>
                <Button
                  type="button"
                  variant="default"
                  onClick={form.handleSubmit((values) =>
                    onSubmit(values, 'published'),
                  )}
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                >
                  {isSubmitting ? 'Publishing...' : 'Save and Publish'}
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


'use client';

import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Image from 'next/image';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import FileUploader from '@/components/ui/file-uploader';
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/popover';
import { ScrollArea } from '@/components/ui/scroll-area';
import { Tabs, TabsContent, TabsList, TabsTrigger } from '@/components/ui/tabs';
import { Image as Images, Video } from '@/db/schema';
import { createClient } from '@/utils/supabase/client';

interface MediaSelectorProps {
  images: Images[];
  videos: Video[];
  value: {
    type: 'url' | 'playbackId';
    value: string | null;
    identifier?: string;
  }[];
  onChange: (
    mediaItems: {
      type: 'url' | 'playbackId';
      value: string | null;
      identifier?: string;
    }[],
  ) => void;
  maxSelection?: number;
  title: string;
  side: 'top' | 'right' | 'bottom' | 'left';
}

export const MediaSelector = ({
  images,
  videos,
  value,
  onChange,
  maxSelection = 8,
  title,
  side,
}: MediaSelectorProps) => {
  const [isPopoverOpen, setIsPopoverOpen] = useState(false);
  const supabase = createClient();
  const router = useRouter();

  // Filter valid videos
  const validVideos = videos.filter(
    (video): video is Video & { playbackId: string } =>
      video.playbackId !== null,
  );

  console.log('MediaSelector Value:', value);
  console.log('MediaSelector maxSelection:', maxSelection);

  // Memoize toggleMediaItem
  const toggleMediaItem = useCallback(
    (mediaItem: {
      type: 'url' | 'playbackId';
      value: string;
      identifier?: string;
    }) => {
      const exists = value.some(
        (item) =>
          item.type === mediaItem.type && item.value === mediaItem.value,
      );

      let newMediaItems;

      if (exists) {
        newMediaItems = value.filter(
          (item) =>
            !(item.type === mediaItem.type && item.value === mediaItem.value),
        );
      } else {
        if (maxSelection && value.length >= maxSelection) {
          if (maxSelection === 1) {
            newMediaItems = [mediaItem];
          } else {
            return;
          }
        } else {
          newMediaItems = [...value, mediaItem];
        }
      }

      onChange(newMediaItems);
    },
    [value, maxSelection, onChange],
  );

  const handleUploadComplete = (
    items: {
      type: 'url' | 'playbackId';
      value: string | null;
      identifier?: string;
    }[],
  ) => {
    console.log('upload complete', items);
    console.log('maxSelection', maxSelection);
    if (maxSelection === 1) {
      onChange(items);
    } else {
      const newItems = [...items];
      console.log('new Items here', newItems);
      items.forEach((item) => {
        if (
          !newItems.some(
            (existing) =>
              existing.identifier === item.identifier ||
              (existing.type === item.type && existing.value === item.value),
          )
        ) {
          newItems.push(item);
        }
      });
      console.log('updating all items');
      onChange(newItems.slice(0, maxSelection));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const channel = supabase
      .channel('videos')
      .on(
        'postgres_changes',
        { event: 'UPDATE', schema: 'public', table: 'videos' },
        (payload) => {
          const updatedVideo = payload.new;
          console.log('payload received');

          if (updatedVideo.playback_id) {
            console.log('updating video', updatedVideo);
            console.log('current value', value);

            // Find and update the processed video in value array
            const updatedValue = value.map((item) => {
              if (item.identifier === updatedVideo.identifier) {
                return {
                  type: 'playbackId' as const,
                  value: updatedVideo.playback_id,
                  identifier: updatedVideo.identifier,
                };
              }
              return item;
            });

            // Only update if there were changes
            if (JSON.stringify(updatedValue) !== JSON.stringify(value)) {
              onChange(updatedValue);
              router.refresh();
            }
          }
        },
      )
      .subscribe();

    return () => {
      supabase.removeChannel(channel);
    };
  }, [supabase, value, onChange, router]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Popover open={isPopoverOpen} onOpenChange={setIsPopoverOpen}>
        <PopoverTrigger
          asChild
          onClick={() => setIsPopoverOpen(!isPopoverOpen)}
        >
          <Button variant="secondary">
            {title} {maxSelection > 1 && `${value.length}/${maxSelection}`}
          </Button>
        </PopoverTrigger>
        <PopoverContent side={side} className="p-4">
          <Tabs defaultValue="images">
            <TabsList className="grid w-full grid-cols-3">
              <TabsTrigger value="images">Images</TabsTrigger>
              <TabsTrigger value="videos">Videos</TabsTrigger>
              <TabsTrigger value="upload">Upload New</TabsTrigger>
            </TabsList>
            <TabsContent value="images">
              <ScrollArea className="h-[400px]">
                <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
                  {images.map((image) => (
                    <MediaThumbnail
                      key={image.id}
                      type="url"
                      itemValue={image.url}
                      thumbnailUrl={image.url}
                      isSelected={value.some(
                        (item) =>
                          item.type === 'url' && item.value === image.url,
                      )}
                      onToggle={toggleMediaItem}
                    />
                  ))}
                </div>
              </ScrollArea>
            </TabsContent>
            <TabsContent value="videos">
              <ScrollArea className="h-[400px]">
                <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
                  {validVideos.map((video) => (
                    <MediaThumbnail
                      key={video.id}
                      type="playbackId"
                      itemValue={video.playbackId}
                      thumbnailUrl={`https://image.mux.com/${video.playbackId}/thumbnail.webp`}
                      isSelected={value.some(
                        (item) =>
                          item.type === 'playbackId' &&
                          item.value === video.playbackId,
                      )}
                      onToggle={toggleMediaItem}
                    />
                  ))}
                </div>
              </ScrollArea>
            </TabsContent>
            <TabsContent value="upload">
              <FileUploader onUploadComplete={handleUploadComplete} />
            </TabsContent>
          </Tabs>
        </PopoverContent>
      </Popover>
      {maxSelection > 1 && value.length > 0 && (
        <div className="mt-4">
          <p>Selected Media Items:</p>
          <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
            {value.map((item, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="relative h-16 w-32">
                <Image
                  src={
                    item.type === 'url'
                      ? item.value || ''
                      : `https://image.mux.com/${item.value}/thumbnail.webp`
                  }
                  fill
                  sizes="(max-width: 768px) 128px, 128px"
                  alt={
                    item.type === 'url' ? 'Selected Image' : 'Selected Video'
                  }
                  className="rounded-md"
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

// Helper component for thumbnails
const MediaThumbnail = ({
  type,
  itemValue,
  thumbnailUrl,
  isSelected,
  onToggle,
}: {
  type: 'url' | 'playbackId';
  itemValue: string;
  thumbnailUrl: string;
  isSelected: boolean;
  onToggle: (item: { type: 'url' | 'playbackId'; value: string }) => void;
}) => (
  <div
    onClick={() => onToggle({ type, value: itemValue })}
    className={`relative h-16 w-32 cursor-pointer ${
      isSelected ? 'ring-2 ring-blue-500' : ''
    }`}
  >
    <Image
      src={thumbnailUrl}
      fill
      sizes="(max-width: 768px) 128px, 128px"
      alt="thumbnail"
      className="rounded-md"
    />
  </div>
);

